# Can I integrate with Power bi, or Tableau and create dashboards on them and display the dashboards to my clients?

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, powerbi-embedded

I'm searching if I can use tool like tableau or power bi to create dashboards fast and display it to the clients in my system

The data cannot be shared publicly

I searched and found the Power BI and Tableau embedded

Didn't use it, and want to know more cause I'm comparing between creating the dashboards manually or using this solution

But need to know if someone used it before, what's the limitations, value, and the pricing,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can start here to Create Reports and dashboard in powerbi. [Create reports and dashboards in Power BI - documentation - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/).

For Embedding, you can start here [Power BI embedded analytics Client APIs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/)

For Pricing, Refer to [Pricing - Power BI Embedded | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/)

If You face any issues, you can reach out to [Support | Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/support/) or ask in [Custom filtered 'powerbi-embedded' questions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-embedded)

For Tableau, Refer to [Embedded Analytics | Create seamless analytics experiences for your customers (tableau.com)](https://www.tableau.com/products/embedded-analytics)

Power BI is cheaper, easier to learn than Tableau. Based on Your data size, budget and visualization needs will determine how much the limitations affect you.

Answer (score 0):

While Power BI seems to be cheaper, I have found the development cycle longer and the product more complex than Tableau (and when sized to an enterprise, the introductory pricing difference isn't a differentiating factor).  In essence you will find folks on both sides of this debate, all tuned to personal preferences.  Choose what matters to you by using the free trials offered by each and figure out which one works best for your situation.